# Kaminari gem modify URL not params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, rubygems, kaminari

I need to modify the URL that kaminari generates not the params. Is it possible ? where do i do it ? I need to remove `/pg-2` from the url, not the params after `?` . I have tried to modify the `url` attribute in the views but no help.

**Example:**

http://www.example.com/xxxx-search/SanJoseCA/pg-2?page=3&page_size=20&pgsz=20